# How do I stop my Nikon 3500 menu from switching off?

Tags: nikon

My Nikon D3500 menu (the one showing ISO, F-Stop, shutter speed) switches off after about 7 seconds.

How do I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Nikon D3500 manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dcnD.png), page 209, Auto off Timers

> This option determines how long the monitor remains on if no operations are performed during menu display and playback (Playback/menus), while photographs are displayed in the monitor after shooting (Image review), and during live view (Live view), and how long the standby timer, viewfinder, and information display remain on when no operations are performed (Standby timer). Choose shorter auto-off delays to reduce the drain on the battery.

[image]

Comment: Can't please some people… you can get a downvote for quoting & providing a link to the manual, with illustration. I don't get it.